# JUnit4 - @Autowired service is null in @Before annotated method

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, junit4, autowired

I have a JUnit test, looking like this:

```
@RunWith(JUnitParamsRunner.class)
public class ProcessnDbUnitTest extends DbunitTestParent {

    @Autowired
    private ProcessRepositiory pr;

    private static List<Object[]> allProcessIds = new ArrayList<>();

    private static Object[][] result = new Object[allPDRIds.size()][];

    private static List<Process> process = new ArrayList<>();

    @Before
    public void before() {
        processes = pr.findAll();
        pr.findAll().stream().forEach(process -> allProcessIds.add(new Object[] { process.getId() }));
        result = new Object[allProcessIds.size()][];
    }
```

DbUnitTestParent:

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = DbUnitApplication.class)
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@SuiteClasses({UserDbUnitTest.class, ProcessDbUnitTest.class })
public class DbunitTestParent extends AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    @After
    public final void flush() {
        em.flush();
    }

}
```

The test themselves doesn't matter in this case. The fields are static because the `@Before` method is fetching stuff for a parametrized test.

When I am debugging the test, I see that in the `before()` method, the autowired `ProcessRepository` is null. The strange thing is that in another, very similar test, everything works fine... Why could this happen?

Comment: Assuming you are refering to Spring's Autowired-Annotation you would need to initialize a Spring context somewhere in the tests

Answer (score 1):

class aka bean set Autowired Annotation need Spring Context to initialize and manage，if you want to use this annotation, you should use SpringJUnit4ClassRunner, if not you can use Mockito to mock it

Comment: Ok. It helped me a bit, but now I have another problem. Most of the tests I am dealing with (i am not the one who wrote them), require three `@RunWith` annotated classes to run. First: `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class`, second `Suite.class`, and third: `JUnitParamsRunner.class`. The base construct was: `class Test1 extends UnitParent`. 
`Test1` is annotaded with `@RunWith(SpringJunit4ClassRunner.class). UnitParent is annotated with `@RunWith(Suite.class)` and extends `AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests`. I have no idea where to put `JUnitParamsRunner.class` to make it work :(

Comment: @dziki you use   `@Runwith(JUnitParamsRunner.class) `  
 `@ContextConfiguration(classes=JavaConfig.class)` on the ProcessnDbUnitTest   
 ```Java                                                                                                                 import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
 
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
public class JavaConfig {}                                                                                          
```

Comment: Yes, I have used it, and it seems to be working for most test cases, BUT, I have some parametrized test cases, which are causing problems. I am using `junitparams`, i have created a static method that should prepare the data, but the data should be fetched from the database, so I have created a `@Before` annotated method: `
    @Before
    public void before() {
        pdr.findAll().stream().forEach(content -> allPDRIds.add(new Object[] { content.getId() }));
        result = new Object[allPDRIds.size()][];
    }`
Where pdr is a jpa repo, allPDRIds is a static list, result is static obj